# C++ Calling private constructor in own class

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, private

Im using VCG library
I have a private constructor since Trimesh cant be copied in my header file MyProcessing.h

```
class MyMesh    : public vcg::tri::TriMesh< std::vector<MyVertex>, std::vector<MyFace> , 

std::vector<MyEdge>  > {

private:
    MyMesh(const TriMesh &mesh);
    MyMesh operator= (const TriMesh &mesh);
```

};

And I have a lot of trouble calling it in my MeshProcessing.cpp file
What im trying to do is create My mesh in there
This is what ive tried

```
vcg::tri::TriMesh< std::vector<MyVertex>, std::vector<MyFace> , std::vector<MyEdge>  > *t_mesh;
MyMesh vcgMesh =MyMesh::MyMesh(*t_mesh);
```

but compiler is copmplaining abou inaccesible element

Any help how to create it will be appreciated

EDIT1

```
private:
// TriMesh cannot be copied. Use Append (see vcg/complex/append.h)


TriMesh operator =(const TriMesh &  /*m*/){assert(0);return TriMesh();}
    TriMesh(const TriMesh & ){}

};  // end class Mesh
```

Comment: What does you MyMesh constructor do? What is the context of the block of code in the middle? Finally why does your mesh inherit from a std::vector?

Comment: Code without private contructor is to be honest copied from documentation page of VCG library. What MyMesh do in my opinion it somehow inherits from trimesh definingh that my Triangulate Mesh will have vectors defining its edges vertices and faces(polygons) More its written here http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/~cignoni/newvcglib/html/basic_concepts.html

Answer (score 2):

Because the given constructor and assignment operator are private, you can only use them within member functions of `MyMesh` or its friend classes. You get a compiler error because

```
MyMesh vcgMesh =MyMesh::MyMesh(*t_mesh);
```

is not in a member function of `MyMesh` or any of its friends.

You will need to make a public constructor or some factory class to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call them outside of the class because you've made them private.

It sounds like you don't want to restrict access, so just make them public :

```
public:
    MyMesh(const TriMesh &mesh);
    MyMesh operator= (const TriMesh &mesh);
```

and provide an appropriate implementation.

Comment: Ive been told that this library use some "standard c++ trick " to restrict using public contructor. And private contructor has to be used. I edited question with copy/paste from header file where trimesh is defined

Comment: @ziker but it's only `TriMesh` constructor is restricted, you don't have to make constructor of your own class private.

Comment: The problem is when i make MyMesh contructor public and do this `vcg::tri::TriMesh< std::vector<MyVertex>, std::vector<MyFace> , std::vector<MyEdge>  > *t_mesh;
 MyMesh vcgMesh =MyMesh::MyMesh(*t_mesh);` compiler complies about `Error 10 error C2248: 'vcg::tri::TriMesh<Container0,Container1,Container2>::TriMesh' : cannot access private member declared in class 'vcg::tri::TriMesh<Container0,Container1,Container2>' e:\skola\fiit\ic source\meshes\meshes\meshprocessing.h 31 1 Meshes
`